# Update Symfony 2.5.10 to 2.7.*

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I want update my project 2.5.10 to 2.7 but I can`t do it. I changed Composer.json

```
...
"symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
...
```

when executed the composer update show me this exception:

composer update
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not load package monolog/monolog in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint >=0.90 <3.0: Invali
  d version string "0.90 <3.0"






  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint >=0.90 <3.0: Invalid version string "0.90 <3.0"



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress
] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

In this file we added something changes and dont know is correctly 100%

Comment: Could you provide your whole `composer.json`? You'll probably need to update some other package as well.

Comment: It looks like monolog/monolog is the problem dependency rather than symfony?

Comment: now I tried with **composer selfupdate** before run the **composer update**, now update correctly

Comment: @Gannon Could you mark your answer as solution, so people know it's been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Recently updated my site to Symfony 2.7

First, you are missing a comma i.e >=0.90, <3.0 This should answer your question.

Second, the best way to upgrade is to download the Symfony Standard Distribution package and compare composer.json values because the Symfony version might not be the only thing you need to upgrade.

Third, and probably just a by-the-way, once I updated my 2.7 Symfony site via composer update, I always got a white screen with no error logs thereafter. I raised the issue on Github and apparently upgrading Sensio distribution-bundle when you have APC cache installed was causing the issue. Restarting Apache which clears the cache solved it.

Happy Coding!

Comment: `composer selfupdate` did it for me too! @Gannon, might want to make that an answer, super helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you might change require-dev part of your json file like this

```
"require-dev": {
    "twig/twig": "~1.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.3,<6.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "~2.3",
    "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.3",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~2.3",
    "symfony/process": "~2.3",
    "symfony/expression-language": "~2.4",
    "matthiasnoback/symfony-config-test": "0.*,>=0.1.1",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
```

It's work for me

Comment: Where do you see the part of `composer.json`?